# How to get the response text from an AJAX request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a JSONP request to a server. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: myURL,
  async: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
  headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json', //this is required by the server
    'key': key   
  },
  success: function() {
    alert('1');
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('2');
  },
  complete: function(){
    alert('3');
  }
});//code indentation
```

When I run the code it errors. But if I open the developers tools in Chrome (ctrl+shift+I) I can see the request under "network". Clicking on it shows the correct response (and shows the request was accepted).

Apologies is there is a really obvious solution (I have tried searching, but with no luck), but at this point I am well and truly baffled. Any help would be really appreciated.

::EDIT::

changing the error function to:

```
error: function() {
  console.log('error', arguments);
},
```

returned the message "jsonCallback was not called" Thanks to Aaron Digulla below.

The response from the server is JSON, not JSONP (checked with JSONlint)

Comment: what is the response logged in the network tab... may be that it is not a jsonp response

Comment: is there any other error in your browser console

Comment: I guess your headers `{ }` is not closed, you're having a typo! is it?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak just bad indentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "it errors", my guess is that you get `alert(2)`. To find out why, log the function arguments to the console:

```
...
error: function() {
    console.log('error', arguments);
},
...
```

jQuery will pass additional information (like the error message) to the function. That should help you understand why it fails.

The same is true for the `success` function which gets the server response, for example.

**[EDIT]**

> I get the error `jsonCallback was not called`

That means your server isn't returning JSONP. JSONP looks like `name({...})` while normal JSON looks like `{...}`. Please check your server's configuration and make sure it actually supports JSONP and that the response looks correct.

I should have seen this from your code:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json', //this is required by the server
}
```

That means you're sending a JSONP/JSON mix which can't work. If you use a certain `dataType`, then let jQuery build the correct headers.

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your suggestion. I get the error "jsonCallback was not called". I have just tried a couple of ways to call it, but they don't work. Unfortunately I do not have the time now to properly look into it. I will try in the evening.

Comment: That means the server isn't returning a JSONP response. What does the response from the server look like? Please edit your question and add this info.

Comment: The response is JSON. Unfortunately, changing dataType to JSON means the requests is blocked due to the same origin policy. I cannot see a way to proceed from here (I cannot use cors on this server), so I suppose the question is answered. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Otherwise I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: I see it now. Okay, you can't mix JSON and JSONP in this way. If the server doesn't support JSONP, then you can't trick it into submission. You really have to change the server side. One way to do this is to add a JSON service to a server under your control (and in the same domain). This service can then use a HTTP library to query the real server and return the response. Or you can set up a JSONP service anywhere in the world which also forwards the request to the original server.

Answer (score 1):

The success function has argument and from that argument you can get the response text.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: myURL,
  async: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
  headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json', //this is required by the server
    'key': key 
  },
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
    alert('1');
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('2');
  },
  complete: function(){
    alert('3');
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this changes nothing. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `async: false` for a jsonp request due to nature of it, adding script tag to handle response method.

Comment: I have removed it, it didn't seem to do anything. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dataType: 'jsonp
```

as you mentioned,the type of data that you're expecting back from the server is jsonp but may be your server will return any other format rather than jsonp.. so check it which type of response your server is returning in under Network in browser console... then if it is not jsonp format, change your respons return type....

Comment: The site is returning JSON (I am seeing now I may have misunderstood what JSONP is). unfortunately changing it to anything else get blocked due to the cross origin policy. The server I'm trying to reach doesn't seem to use cors.

Comment: I think you made a cross domain request. Cross-Domain requests and are blocked by the browser by default.  JSONP is a way of performing cross-domain requests. That's why you are not getting any cross domain error while you are using  dataType: 'jsonp'.